# HTML hoverable dropdown menu semi-working

Tags: html, css

When I hover over "team", I get the 3 drop down menus. When I hover over "A-C", it successfully drops down into the sub menu, however when I then move to hover over "E-N" or "P-Z", it seems locked and continues to only show menus under "A-C".

```
<nav>
        <div class="panel center">
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>                <!--All the pages on the website-->
                <li><a href="SerieA_Tables.html">Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="Teams.html">Teams</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href = "#">A - C </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "#">AC Milan</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">AS Roma</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Atalanta</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Bologna</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Cagliari</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Chievo</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Crotone</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "#">E - N </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "#">Empoli</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Fiorentina</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Genoa</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Inter</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Juventus</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Lazio</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Napoli</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href = "#">P - Z </a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href = "#">Palermo</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Sampdoria</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Torino</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Udinese</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">US Pescara</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
    </nav>
```

//CSS

```
nav {                   /*Lowers the page from the nav boxes*/
height: 40px;
}


nav ul {             /*Manages locations of the nav boxes*/
display:block;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 0 0 -12px;
padding:0px;

}

nav>div>ul>li  {   /*Orders the nav boxes from left to right*/
float: left;
}

nav ul li a {                /* All the boxes like News, Table etc*/
 display:inline-block;
padding: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
background-color: gray;
border:1px solid black;
display: block;
line-height: 40px;
font: 95%  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
color: #66ff66;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 5px;
font-size: 15px;
}

nav ul li a:hover{ /*Highlights box when you hover over it*/
opacity: .7;
text-decoration: none;  
display:block;
}

nav ul ul{             
display:none;
position:absolute;  
padding-left:15px;
}

nav ul ul ul{
padding-left:84px;
margin-top:-50px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{ 
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not able to use bootstarp for this?

Comment: @usrNotFound why should they have to? I never use it

Comment: well so that you wont run into issue like this and they are proven to work in any conditions. Why wold you want to re-invent the wheel when someone has already done it for you of course you can make it better but why spending day or two just to do whats already been done

Comment: @usrNotFound why would you assume he is unable to use Bootstrap for this? Not using Bootstrap is not "re-inventing the wheel". What a ridiculous statement. Maybe he's trying to actually learn how to be a web developer?

Comment: @EdmundReed how many web developer you know write css from scratch or not implement one of many popular frameworks including yourself

Comment: @usrNotFound Every front end developer I know at least knows how to write CSS from scratch even if their current project uses a CSS framework. If you don't know how to write CSS from scratch, you won't be able to successfully maintain a highly customized boostrap site yourself.

Comment: alright, so you are agreeing on implementing what's already there. If so why did you say the statement I made is ridiculous. Now about learning, I totally agree with what you said you can't get better without knowing the basic.

Comment: Because you're assuming if someone can do something with Bootstrap then they shouldn't bother to learn how it actually works. This is toxic advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this CSS setting in your code:

```
nav ul ul ul{
 padding-left:84px;
 margin-top:-50px;
}
```

That `padding-left` lets the element overlap its parent, it still has the same left border as its parent, so when you try to move the mouse over another submenu entry, you are actually still above the sub-sub-menu.

To avoid that, use the usual method for submenus: Apply `position: absolute` to the submenu `ul`(with according left/top settings) and `position: relative to its parent - the`li` of the first sub-menu, like this:

```
nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 67px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Here's the whole example:

```css
nav {
  /*Lowers the page from the nav boxes*/
  height: 40px;
}

nav ul {
  /*Manages locations of the nav boxes*/
  display: block;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 -12px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav>div>ul>li {
  /*Orders the nav boxes from left to right*/
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  /* All the boxes like News, Table etc*/
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 17px 17px 17px 17px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  font: 95% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #66ff66;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  /*Highlights box when you hover over it*/
  opacity: .7;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 67px;
  top: 0px;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="panel center">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <!--All the pages on the website-->
      <li><a href="SerieA_Tables.html">Table</a></li>
      <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="Teams.html">Teams</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">A - C </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">AC Milan</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">AS Roma</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Atalanta</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bologna</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Cagliari</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Chievo</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Crotone</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">E - N </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Empoli</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fiorentina</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Genoa</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Inter</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Juventus</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Lazio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Napoli</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">P - Z </a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Palermo</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sampdoria</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Torino</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Udinese</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">US Pescara</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Addition: I also created a codepen, but it's the same code as the snippet (because the snippet functionality didn't work for a minute or two):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wepXpQ